# What Scope is being used in Angular's $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have been playing around with Angular Material and I wanted to create a $mdDialog that allows a user to enter in information that when saved, will update an object tied to a ng-repeat.

While trying to get this to work and trying out different parameters for mdDialog.show() I was confused about what scope is being used when/why.

This is the first implementation:

```
(function () {'use strict';

angular.
  module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']).
  controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

function AppCtrl($mdDialog, $scope) {
    $scope.lister = [{name:'Matt'},{name:'Steve'}];  
    $scope.showDialog = showDialog;

  function showDialog(evt) {
      $scope.obj = {name:'default'};
      $mdDialog.show({
      targetEvent: evt,
      scope: $scope.$new(),
      template:
        '<md-dialog>' +
        '  <md-content><md-input-container>'+
        '  <label>Name</label>'+
        '  <input ng-model="obj.name">' +
        '  </md-input-container></md-content>' +
        '  <div class="md-actions">' +
        '    <md-button ng-click="close(obj)">' +
        '      Save' +
        '    </md-button>' +
        '  </div>' +
        '</md-dialog>'
    }).then(function(objs){$scope.lister.unshift(objs)});
  }

    $scope.close = function(objs){

        $mdDialog.hide(objs);   
    }
}

}());
```

The behavior of the above code is mdDialog will open with "default" in the Name input field, but if I change the show() parameters to below (key difference is swapping out "scope:" for "controller:"):

```
  function showDialog(evt) {
      $scope.obj = {name:'default'};
      $mdDialog.show({
      targetEvent: evt,
      controller: 'AppCtrl',
      template:
        '<md-dialog>' +
        '  <md-content><md-input-container>'+
        '  <label>Name</label>'+
        '  <input ng-model="obj.name">' +
        '  </md-input-container></md-content>' +
        '  <div class="md-actions">' +
        '    <md-button ng-click="close(obj)">' +
        '      Save' +
        '    </md-button>' +
        '  </div>' +
        '</md-dialog>'
    }).then(function(objs){$scope.lister.unshift(objs)});
  }
```

The behavior of the second implementation is that the mdDialog will open with a blank for the Name input field.

**This is a long setup for this question: Why does the dialog template recognize $scope.obj when "scope: $scope.$new()", but it is not recognized when "controller: 'AppCtrl'"?** I thought both implementations are providing AppCtrl's scope to the dialog.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Dialog is always given an isolated scope
- You can pass data to dialog from parent controller using dependency injection.

```js
function AppController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    var message='message from parent';    
    $scope.showDialog = showDialog;
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3];
    
  
    function showDialog($event) {
       var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
       $mdDialog.show({
         parent: parentEl,
         targetEvent: $event,
         templateUrl:'templateFile.html',
         locals: {
           items: $scope.items
         },
         message:message
         controller: DialogController
      });
      function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, items,message) {
        $scope.items = items;
        $scope.message = message;
        $scope.closeDialog = function() {
          $mdDialog.hide();
        }
      }
}
```

In your first case, you are adding an object to isolated scope of your dialog using

```
$scope.obj = {name:'default'} and its available as obj.name on yr view.
```

In your second case, you are declaring controller for your dialog as 'AppCtrl', but you have not defined it anywhere inside your parent controller, so you are not getting anything on view. AppCtrl is not defined.

Comment: Your explanation of the first case is clear, but for the second case AppCtrl is defined.  The mdDialog is created within that controller.  That's why I thought `$scope.obj = {name: 'default'}` would still be available to the mdDialog's template.

Comment: When u say Controller:"AppCtrl"  for mdDialog, its looking for a function named "AppCtrl", which is in current case not defined. Just have a look at your browser console, you will see error.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use calling scope; you can pass 'isolateScope' parameter like this:

```
$mdDialog.show({
    ....,
    isolateScope: false
});
```

Comment: In addition to that this property does not exist, [the official doc](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#mddialog-alert) says: "The dialog is always given an isolate scope".